# Why do I need to use .inject(0) rather than .inject to make this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inject

I am creating a rails app and have used this code in one of my methods

```
item_numbers.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + i.amount}
```

item_numbers is an array of objects from my item_numbers table. The .amount method that I apply to them looks up the value of an item_number in a separate table and returns it as a BigDecimal object. Obviously the inject method then adds all of the returned i.amount objects and this works just fine.

I am just curious as to why it didn't work when I wrote this statement as

```
item_numbers.inject {|sum, i| sum + i.amount}
```

According to my trusty pickaxe book these should be equivalent. Is it because i.amount is a BigDecimal? If so, why does it now work? If not, then why doesn't it work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What we can read in API:

> If you do not explicitly specify an
>   initial value for memo, then uses the
>   first element of collection is used as
>   the initial value of memo.

So item_numbers[0] will be specified as an initial value - but it is not a number, it is an object. So we have got an error

> undefined method `+'.

So we have to specify initial value as 0

> item_numbers.inject(0){ |sum, i| sum + i }

Comment: You can do a little test
 (10..15).inject do |sum, i|
   p sum
   sum+i
 end

it will return:
10, 21, 33, 46, 60
=> 75

As you can see _sum_ gets first item from array as initial value

Comment: That explains it nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It's because you are accessing `i.amount` as opposed to just plain `i`.  In the version that doesn't work, you're implicitly doing `item_numbers[0] + item_numbers[1].amount + ...`.

One shorthand would be `item_numbers.map(&:amount).inject(&:+)`, but that way can result in two iterations over the list, if `map` doesn't return an enumerator.

If that didn't convince you, look at what gets printed out if we define a method `amount` on Fixnum that prints the value before returning it:

```
irb(main):002:1>   def amount
irb(main):003:2>     puts "My amount is: #{self}"
irb(main):004:2>     return self
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> [1,2,3].inject { |sum, i| sum + i.amount }
My amount is: 2
My amount is: 3
=> 6
irb(main):008:0> [1,2,3].inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i.amount }
My amount is: 1
My amount is: 2
My amount is: 3
=> 6
irb(main):009:0>
```

We can see clearly that `amount` is not called on the first element when a starting value is not explicitly passed in.

Comment: +1 for clear exemple which illustrates the behaviour perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I was also banging my head against it some day, so I tried to visualize it. Hope it helps.[image]